# Change in intensity for poisson variable

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution

Assume that we have two independent Poisson random variables, $X_1 \sim Poi(\lambda)$ and $X_2 \sim Poi(\lambda\psi)$. My question regards inference about $\psi$, which could be seen as the relative change in Poisson intensity from one time period to another. I especially want the MLE of $\psi$. What I have been trying to do is to get the joint likelihood and marginalize $\lambda$, but I haven't been successful. Instead I always end up with an expression where I would have to know $\lambda$ to be able to get the MLE of $\psi$. Hope someone here has a good idea of how to approach this.

Comment: I can't guarantee that I'll have time to answer this, but are $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent? or do they have some sort of non-independent joint density?

Comment: They are independent, thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my question now so that is clear.

Comment: You have data of $X_1$ and $X_2$? I would think $X_1$ constrains $\lambda$ independent of $X_2$. And $X_2$ can only constrain the $\lambda\psi$ product, with no ability to distinguish the two. What logically would constrain $\psi$ if you have no constraint on $\lambda$? (e.g. if $X_1$ was not observed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L(\lambda, \psi)$ be the likelihood function or joint probability density function. (I think you already got it.)

Get   $\frac{\partial \log(L(\lambda, \psi))}{\partial \lambda}$ and
$\frac{\partial \log(L(\lambda, \psi))}{\partial \psi}$

Set two partial derivatives to zero. Get the solution of $\lambda$ and $ \psi$ in term of $X_1$ and $X_2$. That is your answer.

If the analytical form of the solution is unavailable, you need to use computer software to get the numerical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

A numerical solution to the multiplicative parameter is possible, indeed.
Here is a simple solution simulated in R:

```
    > set.seed(4242)
    > 
    > lambda <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 10)
    > mu <- runif(1, min = 0, max = 10)
    > 
    > lambda
    [1] 9.861143
    > 
    > mu 
    [1] 3.477161
    > 
    > x <- rpois(n = 1000, lambda = lambda)
    > y <- rpois(n = 1000, lambda = mu*lambda)
    > 
    > ll <- function(lambda,mu) {
    +   -sum(dpois(x = x, lambda = lambda)*dpois(x = y, lambda = lambda*mu))
    + }
    > 
    > m <- stats4::mle(ll, start = list(lambda = 5 , mu = 5), method = "L-BFGS-B",
    +                lower = c(0.001, .001))
    > ab <- stats4::coef(m)
    > ab
      lambda       mu 
    9.183705 3.674439
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I've reached, based on the answer from a_statistician:

The joint density is given by $$f_{X_1},_{X_2}(x_1, x_2)=e^{-\lambda} e^{-(1+\psi)}\lambda^{x_1+x_2}\psi^{x_2}/x_1!x_2!$$ and the log-likelihood is given by $$l(\lambda, \psi)=-n\lambda-n(1+\psi)+\ln\lambda\sum(x_{i1}+x_{i2})+\ln\psi\sum x_{i2}-\ln(\prod x_{i1}!x_{i2}!).$$ The partial derivative of $l(\lambda, \psi)$ with respect to $\psi$ is $-n+\frac {\sum x_{i2}}\psi$. Setting this equal to zero and solving for $\psi$ yields the MLE of $\psi$: $$\hat\psi=\frac {\sum x_{i2}}n.$$

Comment: What does $n$ mean?

Comment: I use it to denote the sample size of the sample from the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$. A very reasonable question, since thinking about it, I feel that my solution is maybe not intuitive?

Comment: I do not think there are more than one observation. There are only two numbers $X_1$ and X_2$.

Comment: Okey that might be true, makes me a bit confused. How would you write the likelihood function?

Comment: "How would you write the likelihood function?" You already did it by your first equation.

Comment: True. So taking the derivative of the first equation and solving for $\lambda$ and $\psi$ gives the estimators $x_1+x_2$ and $x_2$, respectively.

Comment: Yes. (what should I type? need 10 more characters).

Comment: "Yes" is sufficient :) I just wanted to write the solution out, thanks for all the help!